# Join Showing error in codeigniter on server

Tags: php, codeigniter

i ma using codeigniter joins but its showing error on server side..please check

My Code Is:

```
$this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('posted_ads');
    $this->db->join('post_category','post_category.id='.$cat.' and posted_ads.category=post_category.category');
    $query=$this->db->get();
```

And error showing..

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column '4' in 'on clause'

SELECT * FROM (`posted_ads`) JOIN `post_category` ON `post_category`.`id`=`4` and posted_ads.category=post_category.category

Filename: /home/websray/public_html/mbi/models/postads.php

Line Number: 89
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('posted_ads');
$this->db->join('post_category','posted_ads.category=post_category.category');
$this->db->where('post_category.id',$cat)
$query=$this->db->get();
```